# msgpack.unpackb in Falcon

Tags: python-3.x, msgpack, falcon

I try to learn and deploy sampel code for falcon tutorial in [readthedocs](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/user/tutorial.html).
in [this section](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/user/tutorial.html#testing-your-application) when testing app by `pytest tests` get 1 failed with this title:

> E   msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.

how to solve this problem?

pytest output:

```
tests/test_app.py F                                                      [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________________________ test_list_images _______________________________

client = <falcon.testing.client.TestClient object at 0x7f2cceed5490>

    def test_list_images(client):
        doc = {
            'images': [
                {
                    'href': '/images/1eaf6ef1-7f2d-4ecc-a8d5-6e8adba7cc0e.png'
                }
            ]
        }

        response = client.simulate_get('/images')
>       result_doc = msgpack.unpackb(response.content, raw=False)

tests/test_app.py:26: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.

msgpack/_unpacker.pyx:209: ExtraData
============================== 1 failed in 0.15s ===============================
```

**app.py, images.py and test_app.py are exactly the code in the tutorial without any changes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous step they changed the response type to MessagePack. If you kept JSON as a response type, this may be your problem.

To solve replace

```
result_doc = msgpack.unpackb(response.content, raw=False)
```

by

```
result_doc = json.loads(response.content)
```